# Is Blender 3.4 unable to open or save blend files with a different extension than .blend?

Tags: blend-files

I'm using 2.93 on a regular bases, our unity workflow relies on the fact that we rename .blend files to .uniblend in order to avoid unity to import them while still being visible in Unity explorer.

However it seems that blender 3.4 is unable to open them with file association nor see them from the open dialogue. The same way we can't save files without the .blend suffixe being always added.

Is there a workaround this ?

Comment: As expected 2.93 can't see them with a blend file renamed with that extension here athough you can set Windows to open those files with  Blender. Even after selecting blender 3.4 it opens them in 2.83 here though! You can get .blend1 backup files to open from the file selector by checking them in the filter setting but not to see files with your extension in any Blender version.

Comment: Okay, my .uniblend are associated with blender 2.93 so indeed I didn't try opening them through the dialog.  however, I did try with a .uniblend34 extension to associate with 3.41 and I was unable to open my files (scene opens blank in blender, if renamed to .blend it can open normally). Hence the question for why is it different between 2.93 and 3.4

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. There are no developers here so you'd have to ask them directly on a Blender site but I'd guess that the answer will be that they only support opening of files with the correct extension.